# How to sort a ChoiceField in a ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model that contains a user field.

```
usr = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+', limit_choices_to={'is_active': True})
```

I have a `ModelForm` (shown below) that allows the `usr` to be set: this all works fine. However, the list of users is presented in a random order.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['usr', ]
```

How can I sort the list of active users in the drop down?

Comment: Please show your model form. What do you want the list to be ordered by?

Comment: @Alasdair Done. Sorting the users alphabetically by `username` would be fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One option is to set the [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#ordering) for your model. In your form, the model choice field should use the same ordering.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['username']
```

If you want a different ordering in your model form, then you can use a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) and order the queryset.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    usr = forms.ModelChoiceField(Usr.objects.order_by('username'))
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['usr', ]
```

The disadvantage of this is you lose information from the model field (e.g. `help_text`) unless you duplicate it in the form.

To prevent duplication, you can replace the queryset in the `__init__` method.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['usr', ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['usr'].queryset = self.fields['usr'].queryset.order_by('username')
```

Comment: This is a great answer but I would add that it's not free to add an order to a model - I certainly wouldn't add an ordering to a model just for this purpose. The form-specific methods have no impact on general query performance for the related model and are preferable in my opinion.

Comment: @Richard that's a useful warning, and it's mentioned in the docs as well. For many projects the extra cost of the ordering won't have a noticeable effect, in which case setting `Meta.ordering` is a good solution because it's simple and leads to consistent ordering throughout the project.