# How to Sort drop downs in alphabetical order in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to sort a drop down values in a form field in alphabetical order

Drop down is the field = strategy

I tried using the .order_by  to solve this bug but it some how doesn't seems to solve it

Below is the code i tried

```
class AddForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = Line
    fields = ('analyst','strategy','conviction','startdate','startvalue','target','review','reason','rationale')
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
      super(AddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['Strategy'].queryset = strategy.objects.order_by('name')
```

I get a indentation error and the server stops running... i also tried using

```
strategy = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=strategy.objects.order_by('name'))
```

Didn't work!, where am i going wrong?

Comment: What is order_by('name') name here?

Comment: i just tried to to see if it can be sorted via name... might be wrong

Comment: Is Strategy a model related to Line?

Comment: @Stargazer Strategy is one of the fields in the model Line

Comment: Show us your model, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class AddForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = Line
    fields = ['analyst','strategy','conviction','startdate','startvalue','target','review','reason','rationale']
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(AddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
      self.fields['strategy'].queryset = self.fields['strategy'].queryset.order_by('name')
```

Try this also you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42812014/7470786) SO answer which might be helpful to understand.

Comment: i get a error saying :     self.fields['strategy'].queryset = self.fields['strategy'].queriset.order_by('name')
                                                                                        ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: I think its a typo. `queriset` should be `queryset`

Comment: Yes figured that out @ruddra, thanks for the help its working now

Answer (score 0):

You can order on your model `Meta` class

But as your error is saying, you are indenting your code with TABs and SPACEs in the same block.

Enable the tabs and spaces visualization on your ide and fix that. Basically you have to choose between a tab or a block of spaces.

Python (and other languages) that are indented usually complain if you do that.

Comment: Fixed this, Thanks for your help!